# Автоматический рестарт node.js с помощью pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, есть бот написанный на node.js, из за плохого интернет соединения падает сокет, для возобновления работы нужен перезапуск, установил PM2. Прописал команду pm2 start index.js --watch. Мониторинг показывает что pm2 смотрит за файлом, но как только пропадает соединение, он выводит в логе ошибку и всё, далее скрипт не перезапускает, как настроить что бы при краше сокета pm2 перезапускал файл до тех пор пока не стабилизируется интернет соединение.

> Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])
>   at Client.emit (events.js:186:19)
>   at WebSocketConnection.onError (E:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
>   at WebSocket.onError (E:\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:128:16)
>   at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>   at _receiver.cleanup (E:\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:211:14)
>   at Receiver.cleanup (E:\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:557:13)
>   at WebSocket.finalize (E:\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:206:20)
>
> at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>   PM2 > App [.] with id [0] and pid [6676], exited with code [1] via signal 
>   [SIGINT]
>   PM2 > Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:. id:0
>   PM2 > App name:. id:0 online
>   You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
>   Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND discordapp.com discordapp.com:443
>   at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
>   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)

При добавлении команды `pm2 startup` получаю ошибку :

> E:\Discord Bot> pm2 startup
>   [PM2][ERROR] Init system not found
>   C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\API\Startup.js:192
>         throw new Error('Init system not found');
>         ^
>
> Error: Init system not found
>       at module.exports.CLI.startup (C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\API\Startup.js:192:13)
>       at Command. (C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2:659:9)
>       at Command.listener (C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Command.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\commander\index.js:653:12)
>       at Command.parse (C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\commander\index.js:475:21)
>       at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Ethernet\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\bin\pm2:204:15)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)

Что я опять сделал не правильно ?

Comment: добавь в вопрос текст ошибки

Comment: @norbornen Добавил

Comment: @Дмытрык Да совершенно верно, и перезапускал до тех пор пока не поднимется соединение, ибо если этого не делать бот в офлайне

Comment: @Дмытрык Окей, раз вопрос зашел в тупик, вы как более опытный человек не подскажете что можно использовать для решения моей проблемы ?? PM2 не принципиален по сути !

Answer (score 1):

Директива `--watch`  перезапускает скрипт, если в нем были изменения, а не после падения. Чтобы `pm2` перезапускал скрипт после падения необходимы такие команды `pm2 start nameScript`, `pm2 startup`, `pm2 save`

Comment: Появилась новая ошибка, добавил в вопрос, что я не так сделал ?

Comment: попробуйте без `pm2 startup`.

Comment: не получается, я думаю это связано с этим `There are some external libraries to generate a Windows compatible startup script, please checkout pm2-windows-service or pm2-windows-startup.`  ?

Comment: Добавил `pm2-windows-startup` результат 0

Comment: Со вторым тоже ничего не вышло, как это сделать на win 10 ?

Comment: я так понимаю, это не команды, а модули. Посмотрите их в npm. Если ничего не найдете, тогда может быть стоит воспользоваться другим модулем nodemon или forever

Comment: я установил их но результат как бы так сказать равен нулю. Единственное что я заметил при перезапуске ПК бот поднимается сам, тоесть сервис работает, но если выдернуть интернет или откл. сет. карту и заново вкл. то ничего не происходит, нужно опять ручками запускать или перезапускать ((

Comment: Еще можно использовать `supervisor`.  Там все очень просто `npm install -g supervisor` потом `supervisor yourScript.js`

Comment: Он справится с моей задачей ? Потому как я уже перепробовал почти всё nodemon - крашится вместе с сокетом с таким сообщением `[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`, pm2 не работает полностью с win. Остался forever и supervisor ?

Comment: Ваше приложение точно падает? Или может ошибка отлавливается блоком `try catch` и просто выводится в консоль?

Comment: Да точно падает :) уверен на 101% :)

Comment: Так, как обстоят дела?

Comment: Оставил на работе, бот пока ещё в сети, если до понедельника проживет тогда закрою тему. Единственное я подскажу вам что добавить в ответ и закрою. Спасибо вам за проявленный интерес

Answer (score 0):

Ты должен указывать операционную систему при автостарте.
Пример:

```
$ pm2 startup centos6
```

Где centos6 - твоя операционная система

```
Выбери нужную из списка ниже !
---------en-----------
Hi.
You must write your system.
Example : pm2 startup centos6
centos6  - it your system
----------------------

[ubuntu | ubuntu14 | ubuntu12 | centos | centos6 | arch | oracle | amazon | macos | darwin | freebsd | systemd | systemv | upstart | launchd | rcd | openrc]
```